# Yii accessRules issue - not worked for me

Tags: php, yii, rbac

I was create some methods for different users with different roles. I have 2 type users with roles: user and admin. And try to manage access to some methods which users should not have access. Manage its by accessRules YiiFramework method. Example:

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',
            'roles'=>array('user'),
        ),
        array('allow',  //  allow authenticated users with role 'admin' to access listed actions
            'actions'=>array('chain', 'chainSettings'),
            'roles'=>array('admin'),
        ),
        array('deny',
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

And any users with role "user" have access to actions 'chain' and 'chainSettings'.
May be someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array('allow',
    'roles'=>array('user'),
),
```

Here you need to define what actions are 'users' allowed to access. You didn't define so users can access all actions

Just do similar like you did with 'admin' role, but with different actions, like this:

```
array('allow',
    'actions'=>array('someActionIWantUserToAccess', 'someOtherActionAlso')
    'roles'=>array('user'),
),
```

Comment: If I have 20 actions, I do not want to list it all in accessRules, because only 2 of it I need to close from role "user". I think there are some more elegant solution?

Comment: well, this will do the work... I would also like to hear of more elegant solution, so if you find one please post here